# inline-flex items stack in button element in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I have this example that is using inline-flex:

```css
button {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>12</span>
  <span>asd</span>
</button>
```

The issue is that in Chrome the spans appear next to each other as expected how in FireFox they are stack on top of each other.  Why is FireFox no rendering this as I would expect (or are my exceptions in-correct and Chrome is doing something weird)?

Comment: Why do you need to use flex for button??

Comment: Because in the real world I have an icon and text and in order to get both the icon and text centered without applying specific positioning values (which don't translate when font sizes change and the like) using flex with align-items center is the best way of doing that that I know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35492245/4928642